# huge files spark sort and iterate through the whole data set

Tags: loops, apache-spark

I am new to spark and still don't understand if developer needs to be aware of parallelism. Is it transparent for developer. My problem is the following.
I need to sort records (by cityID and timestamp) from a large number of large files and I need to iterate through the sorted records in a loop and do certain calculation. I can not do group by because order of the records (by timestamp) from the same city  is important for my calculation. How can I do this in spark? 
Using RDD and iterate through it  means I would do all on one machine because I need whole data set and data can not fit on the same machine. Is that right? 
I read a lot about RDDs but I am still missing this part, what if data can not fit on the same machine, same RDD and I want to iterate through all data in one loop.. Do I need to control something? Is there a way to have one loop across the cluster?

Answer (score 1):

In general:

- if computation is fully sequential (loop over records) Spark won't provide any advantage.

Here (if order is important only in groups defined by city):

- partition data by city
- sort by date
- perform sequential computations on each partition

Comment: Thank you so much, yes, order is important only by city and your solution is exactly what I need. Can you please tell me if I should use date frame or RDD and what is rationale for the choice? Also how do I partition by cityID? Thank you for clarifying that spark would not help for fully sequential situation.

Comment: This depends on conditions. For complex conditions probably RDD. You can use custom partitioner  with `(city, date)` as key (there are examples on SO). For simple things `DataFrame` and window functions should be sufficient.

Comment: Thank you! Learned so much from your answers.